# Casting a struct to a void pointer and back again in a different thread changes member values

Tags: c, struct, gdb, pthreads

I am running some code using pthreads, and to pass information to the thread's function, I am using a struct. The struct (called `struct tinfo`) has two fields, one is a pointer to another struct and the other is an int, called `socket`. I am debugging using GDB, and prior to starting the new thread, the `struct tinfo` `socket` field has a value of 4. The thread function accepts a `void *` as its sole argument and the first thing it does it cast it to a `struct tinfo *`. Using GDB I am able to see that prior to this conversion, the value of the `socket` field is still 4. However, upon stepping to the next line, the value changes to 16. I figure this has something to do with the threads, but the 4 should be passed by value and nothing in the function that creates the threads modifies the `struct tinfo` after the thread is created, so I can't see why this would be the case. Below I've attached photos of GDB output, immediately after the thread starts, and then after stepping one line. Also, I will add the code from both the function that creates the threads and the actual thread function itself.

**Immediately after entering the new thread**
(also note that the debugging output prior to `[New Thread 0x7ff...]` is from the function that creates the threads)
[image: Immediately after entering the new thread]

**After stepping to the next line**
[image: After stepping to the next line]

**Code from `handle_connection` (function that creates the threads):**

```
enum tunmux_error handle_connection(struct tunmux *server, int client_socket) {
    struct tinfo info = { .server=server, .socket=client_socket };
    
    pthread_t thread_id;
    if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thread_function, (void *)&info) != 0)
        return TM_ETHREAD;

    return pthread_detach(thread_id) ? TM_ETHREAD : TM_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Code from `thread_function` (function that the threads run):**

```
static void *thread_function(void *payload) {
    struct tinfo info = *(struct tinfo *)payload;
    struct tunmux server = *(info.server);
    int client_socket = info.socket;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That is a flat-out race condition. `info` will expire as soon as `handle_connection` returns, but by that time it is anyone's guess whether you've reaped its content from the address provided to the thread proc. The simplest solution is to dynamically allocate `info` (ex: `malloc`), pass the address thereof, and have the thread function `free` the data once finished with it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I never usually work with threads so I'm used to being able to use a value stack allocated in a caller function, this had me stumped for ages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to a local variable `pthread_create`, then you immediately return from the function that created the thread.  So by the time the thread attempts to read the pointed-to data, its lifetime has ended.  Dereferencing a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to dynamically allocate memory that you pass the the thread function:

```
enum tunmux_error handle_connection(struct tunmux *server, int client_socket) {
    struct tinfo *info = malloc(sizeof *info);
    info->server=server;
    info->socket=client_socket;
    
    pthread_t thread_id;
    if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thread_function, info) != 0)
        return TM_ETHREAD;

    return pthread_detach(thread_id) ? TM_ETHREAD : TM_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then in your thread function, be sure to `free` the allocated memory when you're done with it.

```
static void *thread_function(void *payload) {
    struct tinfo info = *(struct tinfo *)payload;
    free(payload);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Damn I'm a noob sometimes, thanks for pointing that out, I've been scratching my head for a good hour

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted in 5 mins when I'm able to

Comment: They don't *need* to allocate the object dynamically, though that's probably their best option.  They could also use a synchronization object such as a semaphore to help ensure that the first thread does not leave the scope of the automatic object before the new thread has a chance to copy its contents to its own storage.